# Java: Project Euler #14 wrong answer

Tags: java

My code of [Problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) in Project Euler is giving a wrong answer and I can not see what is wrong. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long answer = 0;
        long longest = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            long num = i;
            long counter = 1;
            while (num > 1) {
                if (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
                else num = 3 * num + 1;
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter > answer) {
                answer = i;
                longest = counter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
        System.out.println(longest);
    }
```

Comment: Please use a debugger.

Comment: I am using the debugger of eclipse and there is no error.

Comment: Either the program works fine, or there is an error.

Comment: My output is 35655  \n  324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the length of the chain to the number that produces the chain.

```
if (counter > answer) {
    answer = i;
    longest = counter;
}
```

That should be:

```
if (counter > longest) {
    answer = i;
    longest = counter;
}
```